# Unable to edit the files on Windows Server 2008 which was downlaoded programatically

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-permissions, permissions

I have a scripts which download files from my file server and extract it on c:\home folder @ Windows Server R2.

When I tried to edit and save the extracted files, it shows Access denied, I am able to create new files under it.

I tried to edit the permission but they are locked, Administrator also not able to change permission.

So please let me know whats the issue.

Thanks,
Laxmilal

Answer (score 1):

The issue is "bad" permissions on the file or folder [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

To workaround that, the easiest solution in Windows is to take ownership of the file or folder.

I'll go out on a limb and assume that the GUI would be most appropriate way to show you how to resolve this, so as below...

(Follow links for screenshots)

1. Right click on the file or folder in question, and select `Properties`.
2. [Select the Security tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cclIT.png)
3. [Click `Advanced` and go to the `Owner` tab.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D47G5.png)
4. [Change the `current owner` to the administrative group or user, hitting `Edit` to do so if `UAC` is enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdtlI.png)
5. If it's a folder object, make sure the `Replace owner on subcontainers and objects` box is ticked.
6. Hit `Apply` and close out of all properties tabs.
7. You will now be able to change the permissions on the object to delete it.

**UPDATE:**

In response to your comment about it not working through the GUI:

1. Is the file or folder "locked?"  If you're getting that error, you can't modify the file because some process is currently using it, preventing anything from changing the file.  Your options are to find the process and kill it (through Task Manager, for example), or remove the locking handle, for which I prefer [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/)).
2. If it's not a locked file issue, you should probably use the Windows CLI to change the permissions.  Launch `cmd.exe` "elevated" (<kbd>Right Click</kbd> -> `Run as Administrator`). The best Windows CLI utilities for this task are [XCACLS, for which you can find a good use guide here](http://ss64.com/nt/xcalcs.html) and [CACLS, for which the you can find a good use guise here](http://ss64.com/nt/cacls.html).

Comment: I tried the same but still access is denied.

Comment: @LLM see update.

Comment: Use `icacls`. It's far more versatile than `cacls` or `xcacls`.

Comment: The file and root folder was not locked, i checked it with unlocker utility. 

I also tried run as administrator but no luck.

File shows READ ONLY to all,

Comment: @LLM  Then clear the tick box so that it's **NOT** `read only` first, and then take ownership and/or change permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to take over ownership of these files?

What user account runs the script that downloads these files? Normally the owner of the files is the creator.

Comment: Ownership options are disabled.

I am downloading files using python scripts and the python scripts called by Windows Service. 

Windows Service installed using Administrator account.

Comment: @LLM  Uh, no.  There's no such thing as "disabling ownership" ...  I guess I'll punch up an answer with instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Is `UAC` enabled on the system? In that case, even when you log in with an admin account, that account is unprivileged until you explicitly request elevated privileges (via "run as Administrator"). Can you start a command prompt "as Administrator" and change permissions with `icacls`?

```
icacls C:\YOUR\EXTRACTED\file /grant "Authenticated Users:(CI)(OI)F
```

Comment: I tried the same but giving error:

Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>icacls C:\home\Program.c
s /grant "Authenticated Users:(CI)(OI)F
C:\home\Program.cs: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

Comment: Try `takeown /f C:\home\Program.cs /r /a` in the same administrative command prompt.